# Accessing env from modules called by Fabric

Tags: python, python-2.7, fabric

I'm trying to use Fabric as a tool for deployment of an Extract, Transform, and Load process (which uses Python 2.7 scripts). I understand that you can set arbitrary key-value items in the Fabric environment (env dict). But how do you access them in modules called by Fabric?

For example:

```
from fabric.api import local
import my_module

def myfunc():
    my_module.myfunc()
```

And my_module.py:

```
def myfunc():
    do_something_with_env()
```

Right now i'm just passing in the necessary env items via function parameters. Is there a more pythonic way to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

Just use `from fabric.api import env` and it will contain the global values.